# Python win32: FillSolidRect only works if call >= 20 times

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I'm trying to draw a rectangle on my screen using the win32 python libs.  For some reason it works if I call FillSolidRect 20 times in a row, but if I call it less than that it doesn't work.  Can anybody give a hint as to why?

```
import time

from ctypes import windll
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import win32ui, win32con

screen_width, screen_height = GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1)
dc = windll.user32.GetDC(0)
screen_dc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle( dc )
shot_dc = screen_dc.CreateCompatibleDC()
shot_bitmap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
shot_bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(screen_dc, screen_width, screen_height)
shot_dc.SelectObject(shot_bitmap)
shot_dc.BitBlt((0, 0), (screen_width, screen_height), screen_dc, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)

' Have to draw >= 20(?) times or nothing will get drawn (for some reason).'
for i in range(20):  screen_dc.FillSolidRect((0,0,100,100), 0x000000),

time.sleep(1)
screen_dc.BitBlt((0, 0), (screen_width, screen_height), shot_dc, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)
```

Comment: Wonder if this could be a result of [GDI batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144844%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes.  Adding `windll.gdi32.GdiFlush()` after a single draw fixes the problem.  Feel free to submit this as an answer if you want the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows queues/batches certain GDI operations to enhance performance.  See [GdiFlush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144844%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for more information on how to override this.